# How to get image path from input type file to img src using angular

Tags: angularjs, image-uploading

I want to see an image that i just selected from input type file into an image tag using angular js

I have tried same code for displaying numbers and text from on input box to another input box or html attribute

```
<input type="file" ng-model="img_path">
<img src="{{img_path}}">
```

Comment: Please take reference from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Comment: The method uses jquery whereas i want to use angular